# serialization c# - objects collection

Tags: c#, serialization

I just started programming in C# and I have problem with Serialization

What I want to do:

```
<Products>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Product>
    <name>Samochod</name>
    <price>20</price>
    <mass>1000</mass>
  </Products>
<Products>
```

My idea:

```
  [XmlRoot("Product")]
    public class Product
    {

        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("price")]
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("mass")]
        public double mass { get; set; }



        public static void serialization()
        {
            id iD = new id();
            List <id> idlist = new List<id>();
            List<Product> listprod = new List<Product>();
            idlist.Add(new id() {ID = 1});
            listprod.Add(new Product() { name = "Samochod", price = 20, mass = 1000 });

            XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute("Products");
            TextWriter textwriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Products.xml");
            XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>),root);
            xmlserializer.Serialize(textwriter, listprod);
            textwriter.Close();


        }


    }

    [XmlRoot("ID")]
    public class id:Product
    {
        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Unfortunately, there is error during compilation. So could you give me some tips/directions how to fix this?

Sorry, there isn't error. Now it looks like:

```
<Products> 
      <Product>
        <ID>0</ID>
        <name>Samochod</name>
        <price>20</price>
        <mass>1000</mass>
      </Products>
 <Products>
```

But, when I changed this line:

```
idlist.Add(new id() {ID = 1});
```

to this:

```
listprod.Add(new id() {ID = 1});
```

Then I have an error:

```
There was an error generating the XML document.
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting?

Comment: This worked just fine for me producing exactly the XML file you want. You should provide more details on the errors you are getting.

Comment: Just compiled and ran fine (albeit with a slightly different xml that you want). I had to change the path, because I don't have access to the C:\ folder on my machine without elevating privileges. As per Justin's comment - what error are you getting?

Comment: Why would you want the ID tag *outside* of the Product tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your `idlist` ends up being unused. Since ID is really an atribute of the `Product`, I would suggest this to simplify the code like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("price")]
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("mass")]
    public double mass { get; set; }



    public static void serialization()
    {
        List<Product> listprod = new List<Product>();
        listprod.Add(new Product() { ID = 1, name = "Samochod", price = 20, mass = 1000 });

        XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute("Products");
        TextWriter textwriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\Products.xml");
        XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>), root);
        xmlserializer.Serialize(textwriter, listprod);
        textwriter.Close();
    }
}
```

You should then get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Product>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <name>Samochod</name>
    <price>20</price>
    <mass>1000</mass>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Comment: But my task is to make <ID>1<ID/> outside list of Product tag

Comment: Then you should be adding it to the same collection (`listprod`) since your `ID` class is derived from `Product` class.
So technically, you could do that, but that's wouldn't be "good" XML - your ID and Product nodes appear at the same level and are of the same type essentially. Isn't an id usually a property of a Product?

Comment: So that would look like this:


    id iD = new id();
    List<Product> listprod = new List<Product>();
    listprod.Add(new id() {ID = 1});
    listprod.Add(new Product() { name = "Samochod", price = 20, mass = 1000 });

Comment: <ID> used to be a property od a Product, but I have changed it specially to practice